# How can I save default settings with HxD

Tags: hex-editor

I use HxD to view files (binary and string data)

The issue I have is when I open the application, it defaults to

```
16 bytes per row
ANSI
hex
```

I change it to 32 ANSI DEC as I only need it with that format. The problem is, next time I open the app, the changes are not persisted.

I have emailed the dev, but not had a reply as of yet, but is there a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the "View" dropdown try "Extras -> Options... - > View" and change global settings here.